# Three AutoIT script causing issue

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, autoit

All,

I have Selenium script which attach documents to Transaction. I am using AutoIT. Now, the problem I am facing is: I have to attach 3 documents (one by one). My steps are: I execute AutoIT script. Then script click on Browse 1 - button in my transaction screen - File Upload pop up appears. My Address of file is pasted correctly in text area as well.

But when AutoIT script click on Open button - another File Upload window appears.

I did added some wait in my script before clicking on Browser 2 button. But somehow I am missing something which is causing this problem.

Another thing is that: Same script works sometimes. Failure is more than success.

```
WinExists ("TITLE")

While 1
  Select
     case WinExists("File Upload")

            WinActivate("File Upload")

            Sleep(5000)

            Local $sTestPath = _PathFull(@ScriptDir & "\ABC.jpg")

            ControlClick("File Upload", "", "Edit")

            Send($sTestPath)

            Sleep(5000)

            Send("{ENTER}")

            Sleep(5000)

            Exit

    Case WinExists("Choose File to Upload")


            WinActivate("Choose File to Upload")

            Sleep(5000)

            Local $sTestPath = _PathFull(@ScriptDir & "\ABC.jpg")

            ControlClick("File Upload", "", "Edit")

            Send($sTestPath)

            Sleep(5000)

            Send("{ENTER}")

            Sleep(5000)

            Exit

    Case WinExists("Open")


            WinActivate("Choose File to Upload")

            Sleep(5000)

            Local $sTestPath = _PathFull(@ScriptDir & "\ABC.jpg")

            ControlClick("File Upload", "", "Edit")

            Send($sTestPath)

            Sleep(5000)

            Send("{ENTER}")

            Sleep(5000)

            Exit

EndSelect

WEnd
```

Comment: If we don't have a working example to reproduce the problem it is very difficult to help you. + I find really difficult to understand what you want to do.

P.S. WinExists ("TITLE") does nothing.

Comment: @user2530266 - The situation is that I need to attach document to my transaction. Now, I use 3 diff browsers for test. Each Browser - Filr Upload title is diff. So, based on that, I have added this WinExists("Firefox Open"),  WinExists("IE Open") and  WinExists("Chrome Open") - so based on broswer, it will select the piece of code. As I said. its working fine sometime.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use send.

> Send ( "keys" [, flag] ) - Sends simulated keystrokes to the active
>   window.

Better way:

> ControlSend () can send characters to targeted window (can be inactive).

Most reliable way:

> ControlSetText () - Sets text of a control.

Play with AutoitWindowInfo tool and tweak the script below if needed.

```
#RequireAdmin ;Will give your script a permission elevation (sometimes its needed)
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 1) ;1=start, 2=subStr, 3=exact, 4=advanced, -1 to -4=Nocase
Opt("WinSearchChildren", 1) ;0=no, 1=search children also

WinActivate("File Upload")
WinWaitActive("File Upload","",10)
ControlFocus("File Upload","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("File Upload","","Edit1","dropdowns.jpg")
ControlSend("File Upload", "", "Edit1", "{ENTER}")
```